# "Invalid Path in Zip Entry": Error Uploading API Proxy Bundle to Apigee using Pulumi in Python

Tags: apigee, pulumi, pulumi-python

I'm facing the same issue I think. Let me describe mine.

I'm trying to upload an API proxy bundle to Apigee using the `gcp.apigee.Sharedflow` resource in Python with Pulumi. The bundle I am trying to upload is structured as follows and named `my-proxy.zip`:

```
-- apiproxy
    |-- my-proxy.xml
    |-- proxies
    |   `-- default.xml
    `-- targets
        `-- default.xml
```

However, when I attempt to deploy this bundle using Pulumi, I receive the following error message:

```
gcp:apigee:Sharedflow (my-proxy):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * Error creating SharedFlow: googleapi: Error 400: bundle contains errors
    Details:
    [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/edge.configstore.bundle.BadBundle",
        "violations": [
          {
            "description": "zip entry in bundle has invalid path",
            "filename": "apiproxy/proxies/default.xml"
          },
          {
            "description": "zip entry in bundle has invalid path",
            "filename": "apiproxy/targets/default.xml"
          },
          {
            "description": "zip entry in bundle has invalid path",
            "filename": "apiproxy/my-proxy.xml"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
        "requestId": "11637400726346568001"
      }
    ]
```

Interestingly, when I upload the same zip file via the GCP console for creating API Proxies in Apigee, the proxy is created without any issues. This leads me to believe that the problem might be related to how Pulumi or the `gcp.apigee.Sharedflow` resource is handling the bundle.

Here's the relevant portion of my Pulumi code for context:

```py
gcp.apigee.Sharedflow(
        "my-proxy",
        config_bundle="my-proxy.zip",
        org_id=org_name,
        opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(
            depends_on=[bundle_resource]
        )
    )
```

I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem, or can anyone suggest what might be causing these "invalid path" errors when using Pulumi to deploy to Apigee?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pulumi. From what you've shared and from the Pulumi docs, it appears you are using a package to deploy a shared flow. On Apigee, an API proxy and shared flow(kind of like a reusable library that's attached to a proxy) are different.

Comment: I also noticed that @Ram. In fact it's not the same and finally, creating a sharedflow visually I have the same error. Probably because the content of my files is not what is expected for a sharedflow bundle.